# How to over 500000 cpuunits on OpenVZ

Tags: virtual-machines, openvz, proxmox

I have a OpenVZ and i would like to allocate more than 500000 cpu units.
But the max i can set is 500000.
Does he have a solution to give more power to my vm?

According to all the sources I read (openvz wiki, various mailinglists, forums, ..) the values of the cpuunits max: 500000, min 8.

```
vzcpucheck
Current CPU utilization: 526000
Power of the node: 1356862
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I ask what the hell for?

Check: http://kb.simplywebhosting.com/idx/6/067/article/

The "Unit" has no specific meaning but defines priority.

So, one 10, another 20 means the second gets - when CPU is the limit - twice as much power than the first.

Over 500k in granularity sounds - non,sensible.

Comment: Thank you! I thought the cpu units for the power granted to my vm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like TomTom said, OpenVZ CPUUnits are a relative measure. If you have 2 VMs and grant each of them equal CPUUnits (100, 1000, whatever) they will get an equal share of the host CPU. If you grant one double, triple, etc, it will get double or triple the priority of the CPU usage. There is a tool called vzcpucheck which will measure your CPU and distribute appropriate CPUUnits. Here is the OpenVZ wiki article: http://openvz.org/Resource_shortage#cpuunits

Hope that helps!